# How could I downgrade the swiftlint on my m1 pro mac

Tags: macos, homebrew, swiftlint

I want to downgrade the swiftlint version on my MBP M1 Pro.
I installed it using `brew install swiftlint`
In `homebrew/Cellar/swiftlint` the folder is `0.49.1` which I guess is the version installed on my machine.

**I googled and tried a few methods. But non of them worked for me.**

First:
`brew install <url of older github raw file>` is not working

Second:
`brew install swiftlint@0.47.0` was also not working

Third:

- I downloaded portable_zip of `0.47.0` form github, extracted and created a new folder `homebrew/Cellar/swiftlint/0.47.0` and pasted the content there. After double clicking on the executable file swiftlint starts running.
- Then ran `brew switch swiftlint 0.47.0` but it was also not working
- I also tried deleting the alias from `homebrew/bin/swiftlint` and pasted new alias from `homebrew/Cellar/swiftlint/0.47.0` folder's executable there, but it was also not working.

Can anyone help me out what I am doing wrong, and what should be the correct steps.
**I am new to macOS.**

Comment: Did you first try to uninstall swiftlint? Seems to me that would be the first thing to do.

Comment: Yes, I tried uninstalling. And then doing Third(a) and Third(c) step. 
I guess I'm missing something else also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a work around. Earlier I wasn't aware how files, applictions works in MacOS, where does the data for applications go.

I am writing down the steps for `swiftlint`, maybe similar steps might be used to downgrade any other tool on MacOS (on M1 pro macbook).

What worked for me was:

- First of all I installed xcode's older version manually, `xcode-select --print-path` was different so I changed it with `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.
- Then I uninstalled the `swiftlint` using brew uninstall command.
- Then from github I downloaded `.pkg` file of exact version I wanted, and installed it.
- Also downloaded `portable zip` from same repository and extracted the contents and pasted them in `homebrew/Cellar/swiftlint/`
- Made one alias of executable file of the previous step extracted files and pasted that in `homebrew/bin`

Then this exact version of `swiftlint` was installed for me, and now it works fine.
Hope this helps someone.